# Bash compare all values in array

Tags: arrays, bash

```
#!bash
ARRAY=(one two three four five)
```

List all possible combinations with no repetition and array is not in order and the output does not need to be in order.

> Desired output

```
one two
one three
one four
one five
two three
two four
two five
three four
three five
four five
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.  What have you tried?  Is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **bash** `for` looping:

```
arr=(two four one three five)
len=${#arr[*]}

for (( i=0; i < $len; i++ )); do
    for (( j=$((i+1)); j < $len; j++ )); do 
        echo "${arr[$i]} ${arr[*]:$j:1}"
    done
done
```

The output:

```
two four
two one
two three
two five
four one
four three
four five
one three
one five
three five
```